# Can't start Idea 14.1.1

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed Intellij Idea 14.1.1
After setting up by wizard screen on first run then error caught:

```
    Internal error. Please report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'org.intellij.images.fileTypes.impl.ImageFileTypeManagerImpl'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:738)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:708)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'org.intellij.images.fileTypes.impl.ImageFileTypeManagerImpl'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initStandardFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:273)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.<init>(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageWriterSpi could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(IIORegistry.java:210)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(IIORegistry.java:138)
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:65)
    at org.intellij.images.fileTypes.impl.ImageFileTypeManagerImpl.createFileTypes(ImageFileTypeManagerImpl.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initStandardFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:270)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
    at javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider.<init>(IIOServiceProvider.java:76)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderWriterSpi.<init>(ImageReaderWriterSpi.java:231)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi.<init>(ImageWriterSpi.java:213)
    at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageWriterSpi.<init>(CLibJPEGImageWriterSpi.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
    ... 45 more
```

note:

- source : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/
- there's similar problems found on google, but mine is different from them
- i'm using jdk 7
- ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: So have you tried https://youtrack.jetbrains.com? For example https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137147

Comment: @Meo yes, but no luck

Comment: Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: @yole i'm using jdk7

Comment: Had the same issue on JDK7 and JDK 8. Issue submitted to: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139178.  I reinstalled 14.0.4 and there were no issues starting up.

Comment: @Will yeah, finally I just uninstalled it and install 14.0.4 too :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply deleting:

~/Library/Java/Extensions

(which contains the offending JAI jar) does the job on a Mac.

Relevant issues:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137147

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139178

Comment: I can't find similar directory on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Thanks! It seems that `rm ~/Library/Java/Extensions` helped me with Android Studio 1.2 not starting issue, it gave same exception.

Comment: How to fix this issue in Windows operating system?

Comment: Just had to do this on Win7 too.  I removed all the jai jars in:  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\ext

Comment: @Will i am working on Windows 8.1 and removing the jai jars from the ext folders does not work  for me. Any clue what might work ?

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem on OSX seems to have a root cause of the commonly used JAI extension jar files being somewhat mis-configured with a null vendorName. If you need the JAI extensions for some reason (because, for example, your local GeoServer upgrade re-installs them in `~/Library/Java/Extensions`) then a work-around is to create a `~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/idea.vmoptions` file that contains ONLY:

`-Djava.ext.dirs=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext`

That seems to override OSX Java 6's default behavior of checking the user's `~/Library/Java/Extensions` directory in addition to the system's extensions on application start up.

If you are using some other JRE version/operating system then adjusting those paths or making sure that the Java extension directory that the application that needs JAI is different from the one that IntelliJ uses may help. At worst you might install two JDK/JRE's and give each application a different JAVA_HOME value.