# Pycharm 4.5 CE crashes on launch on OS X 10.8.5

Tags: macos, pycharm

I upgraded from Pycharm 4.0 (which worked fine) to 4.5 community edition on Mac OS 10.8.5.

It crashes on launch after bouncing a bit in the dock.

The log files, console, all show nothing.

I'm running java 1.6.0_65, and have Python 2.7, Jython, PyPy via Macports.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've installed [Apple's Java for OS X 2014-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) (at least).

Try to delete ~/Library/Java/Extensions, see the issue [IDEA-137147](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137147).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer [for IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590233/cant-start-idea-14-1-1/30334985#30334985), if you can't delete `~/Library/Java/Extensions`, i.e., because you need it's contents (likely JAI jars) as part of other applications, you can create a file, `pycharm.vmoptions` in `~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm40` with contents:

`-Djava.ext.dirs=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext`

to override OSX Java 6's default behavior of checking the user's ~/Library/Java/Extensions directory in addition to the system's extensions on application start up; but only for PyCharm.